# Replying to mail with attachments using Zend framework

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

Hi guys I'm integrating basic email capabilities in my application and I would like to be able to incorporate a decent reply / forward email facility. I have it covered with sending my own uploaded attachments but what about in situations where I recieve a message in my inbox with attachments and wish to forward that same message along with the attachments already attached to it as well as be able to choose which of the attachments to include and which not to.

Answer (score 0):

Auto save/dowload the files in a temporary folder.
When a user (re)sends the email check through a form which of the attachments he wishes to send, and with the information of the form re-attach the files